# Is there any advantages in using VS2010 for TDD vs VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, tdd, agile

I want to push our management to migrate to VS2010 sooner. The new feature in our project is to migrate to TDD.

I want to convince that there are endless benefits of migrating to TDD and VS2010 simultaneously.

Is there really?

VS2008 Pro vs VS2010 Pro - whats good can be used in terms of unit-testing?

(sorry for the dumb question but the project manager is not very bright so I have to move down to his level :-P).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd998313(VS.100).aspx Might be worth a read, or http://blogs.objectsharp.com/cs/blogs/dave/archive/2009/11/07/test-driven-development-with-vs-2010.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there are advantages.  The MVC pattern is better suited to TDD.  And with Visual Studio 2010 it will automatically stub out new classes as you write your unit tests that reference them.

More details here:
http://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/rdn-express/2009/06/test-driven-development-in-vs-2010.aspx

-Krip